# Omnet++ fatal error: 'inet/common/INETDefs.h' file not found

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

I am trying to extent a mobility module in Inet 4.2 under Onmet++ v5.6, the issue is that I get the "fatal error: 'inet/common/INETDefs.h' file not found" error during importing the INETDefs.h file.

```
#ifndef CustomizedMobility_H_
#define CustomizedMobility_H_

#include "inet/common/INETDefs.h"
#include "inet/mobility/single/TractorMobility.h"

namespace inet{
class CustomizedMobility : public TractorMobility{
protected:
    virtual void setTargetPosition() override;
    virtual void move() override;
    Coord vLastPosition;
};
}//ns inet

#endif /* CustomizedMobility_H_ */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved just wright click on the project, choose properties, then under omnet++ section choose MakeMake and click on the src folder. After that choose option from the right side section. then have a look at the following figure.

[image: Figure]

Answer (score 1):

Hi for me what worked has adding include paths from referenced proyects (inet), its in the window Link from Properties -> OmNet -> Makemake Options -> Links

[image]